# How does domain administrator reset local administrator password on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Is it possible for a Domain Administrator to reset the Local Administrator on a machine Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Did you have more of a question here?  If you are wanting to do this for all domain computers, you should be looking at LAPS.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/3062591.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the server is on the domain and the Domain Admins are in the Administrators local group on the server (by default they are when joined to the domain).

Log on to the server as the domain admin account, go to Computer Management, Local Users and Groups, Users.  Then right click the Administrator account and set the password or whatever you are needing to do.

NOTE: The local Administrator account should really be disabled and remain that way.  You should be creating separate local accounts if really required and giving them local admin privileges, or ideally just using domain accounts that are part of the local admins group.